# Why JVM first request Application ClassLoader to load a class when eventually this request is delegated to Bootstrap classloader?

Tags: java, class, classloader, classnotfoundexception

As per my reading, When JVM needs a class, the following events takes place :

1. Request is sent to application classloader to load the class.
2. Application class loader delegates the request to Extension Class loader.
3. Extension class loader delegates request to Bootstrap class loader.
4. Bootstrap Class loader try to load the class from Boot strap class path. If class is found there, it is loaded.
5. If class is not present in bootstrap class path, then Extension Class loader try to load the class from Extension class path.
6. If class is not present even in extension class path then application Class loader try to load the class from Application class path i.e. CLASSPATH environment variable path.
7. If class is not present even there, ClassNotFoundException is thrown.

**QUESTION:**
When each class loading request has to ultimately go to Bootstrap classloader, then why does JVM takes the overhead of requesting Application Class loader first and then let it delegate the request gradually to Bootstrap Class loader. 
Why doesn't it directly request Bootstrap class loader?

Is there any specific reason for this, or there is something i am missing and i need to read more about?

Answer (score 3):

The JVM doesn't specifically look for the application-level class loader. Instead, when class loading for class `C` is triggered (either by loading a class `D` that refers to a class not yet loaded, or through reflection from within class `D`) without specifying a class loader, the load request is directed to the defining loader for `D`, which is usually the application loader. The default strategies are then to delegate to the extension and bootstrap loaders, but this behavior isn't technically required.

One major reason to do this is that if you have some shared type, it needs to be defined in some ancestor class loader of all of the cooperating classes that use it, because types are identified at runtime by the combination of their full names and their loader. (OSGi makes use of this rule to restrict the visibility of classes to bundles which specifically declare dependencies on them.)

Note that if the class `D` (say, `java.net.URL`) was defined by the bootstrap loader, then any class `C` that it loads (say, `java.lang.String`) is immediately loaded by the bootstrap loader.

[The JVM Specification's section on loading and linking](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3) provides the definitive details on the resolution and loading process.

Comment: As you said, "The default strategies are then to delegate to the extension and bootstrap loaders, but this behavior isn't technically required". This exactly is my question. What was the thought process behind keeping this behavior?

Comment: @GauravKumar I was updating, and I think I answer that now. Basically, you want types to be defined by the highest-common-ancestor classloader so that they can be shared by all of the child loaders.

Comment: Can you provide an example to explain what you are trying to say here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 principles in class loader：

1. delegate
2. Visibility
3. Uniqueness

> check this article: http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.id/2012/12/how-classloader-works-in-java.html

As for Visibility principle, The **Application or System** class loader could see all the loaded class files, but **Bootstrap or Primordial** couldn't.

> as **Application** class loader is child of **Bootstrap** class loader

To make sure that a class is loaded only once, which makes sure the *uniqueness*, the request for loading a class should be firstly sent to **Application / System** class loader.

Hope this will help.